# Could creatures similar to old testament angels actually fly?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-reality, angels, flight

I am writing a novela which includes beings similar to the depiction of angels in the Old Testament.
Edit: not relevant to the question (The story is set in the present day, England, but the beings hide from people, so few know of their existence.)
These beings are many winged creatures covered in eyes. Although they are preternaturally strong, they are not innately capable of levitation (Via magic or otherwise).

### Edited to include info from comments.

About 12 feet in wingspan but it can very from 10 to 14 feet.
They can fly around but often hover. They do not have legs however they are capable of takeoff from a stationary position on the ground. (I understand that that may be physically impossible) They do not need to eat as they derive sustenance from magic they pull from another dimension. Also, they reproduse asxualy by buding, some of the wings fall off and grow into new creatures.

To clarify these are not actually angels (spiritual beings created as god's messengers extera). They are angel like creatures that exist in the physical world.

Would such a being be able to fly?

This image is close to the description I was going for:

[image: old testament angel]

[image]
Another example is Proginoskes from [A Wind in the Door](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wind_in_the_Door).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120592/discussion-on-question-by-smorb42-could-creatures-similar-to-old-testament-angel).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the laws of physics as we know them, probably not. They probably couldn't exist either, with all those huge masses and widely dispersed brain cells and lack of mouths and whatnot. The Square-cube law means their size makes them infeasible, their shape is very unstable, and There are far more efficient ways to achieve levitation and flight at the very least.

However, the whole point of biblical angels is that they are beyond the laws of physics as we know them; they follow their own rules. If a Biblical Angel could be explained by science as we know it today, it would not really be a Biblical angel.

Comment: Even without magic, that wingspan is not infeasible to being able to fly naturally.  The wandering albatross has been shown to have a wingspan capacity of almost 12 feet.  Fossil records have identified a prehistoric bird skeleton with a 17 foot wingspan.  The hovering part, on the other hand, not so much.  "If a Biblical Angel could be explained by science as we know it today, it would not really be a Biblical angel." - Lots of L.S.D. or other hallucinogens!